# Alternate for function Timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, db2

I want to modify below query to avoid using function Timestamp. Since this function is being used the index is not used.  Please let me know what alternatives can be used. This query is for DB2 database.

```
SELECT *                  
  FROM   Capacity CPC          
 WHERE TIMESTAMP(CPC.CPC_DATE,CPC_TIME) BETWEEN            
       CURRENT TIMESTAMP + :Input_number HOURS
   AND                                                   
       CURRENT TIMESTAMP + :Input_number HOURS
```

Comment: I think your best option would be to create a computed `TIMESTAMP` column with an index on it, or a functional index if your DB2 version supports it.

Comment: Side note: please [never use `BETWEEN` for date/time types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (the post talks about SQL Server, but the underlying problem is actually platform agnostic).  The primary concern here would be getting the same result if you paged the query.  Date/time types are positive, contiguous-range types, and should always be queried with an exclusive upper-bound (`<`)

Answer (score 0):

You have to decompose date range and time range separately. The time part only needs to be checked if it in the same date part of the range:

```
SELECT *
FROM Capacity CPC
WHERE 
CPC_DATE >= DATE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - :Input_number HOUR)
AND
CPC_DATE <= DATE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP + :Input_number HOUR)
AND
CPC_TIME >= 
    CASE WHEN CPC_DATE = DATE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - :Input_number HOUR)
      THEN TIME(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - :Input_number HOUR)
      ELSE '00:00:00'   
    END
AND 
CPC_TIME <= 
    CASE WHEN CPC_DATE = DATE(CURRENT TIMESTAMP + :Input_number HOUR)
      THEN TIME(CURRENT TIMESTAMP + :Input_number HOUR)
      ELSE '24:00:00' 
    END
```

Comment: Please don't use `BETWEEN` with positive contiguous-range types (like date/time); if this query is paged based on the hour, you'd end up selecting things in the last hour on both sides.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty much hopeless as your data is not in 2NF: `CPC_DATE` and `CPC_TIME` should be single column `CPC_DATETIME`. If you don't need the time component in that form, you can still query from `YYYY-MM-DD-00:00:00` to `(YYYY-MM-DD plus one day minus one second)` and retain using an index.

Comment: "pretty much hopeless"?  I think not.